# how to design images inside a cardview?

Tags: android-studio

I'm trying to achieve something like this:

[image]

as you can see the car image is out of the cardview. I want to do the same.

Here is what I tried:

```
  <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/d2"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            app:cardCornerRadius="20dp"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            android:padding="20dp"
            app:cardElevation="2dp"
            >
            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/image_container"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/sea"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/sea"
                    android:layout_gravity="top"
                    android:maxHeight="400dp"/>

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/play"
                    android:layout_marginTop="-30dp"
                    android:layout_width="120dp"
                    android:layout_height="120dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/yonuswheal" />

            </RelativeLayout>

        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

but here is how it looks for me:

[image]

The whale is supposed to be out of the cardView just like the car example above. How can I fix this?